# Mathematica - Exclude a String from a String Search

Tags: pattern-matching, wolfram-mathematica, string-matching

I'm trying to select the most frequently occurring key words on a table. 
I need to search for the number of occurrences of a word in a list that DOES NOT include a given second, third, fourth, etc. word.

For example, I need to search for the number of times the word "lollypop" appears in a list that does not include the word "candy".

This code will return the number of times the word "lollypop" appears:

```
rt = Parallelize@
 Cases[MemoizeTable["Candy_table.txt"], 
  x_List /; 
   MemberQ[x, 
    s_String /; 
     StringMatchQ[s, ("*lollypop*"), IgnoreCase -> True]], {1}];
```

I tried adding `StringFreeQ` to exclude "candy", and I tried adding `Nor` where one would add `Or` in the string search, but I wasn't sure how to do that/where to put it/them..?

I need a `"this" BUT NOT "that"` code, basically.

Comment: What is `MemoizeTable`?  Is that a new function in mm8, or something you wrote?  What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
excludeList = {"candy", "other"};
toCount = "lollypop";

numberOfToCount[list_, tocount_, excludeList_] := 
  If[And @@ ((! MemberQ[list, #]) & /@ excludeList), 
     Count[list, tocount], 
     "Excluded"];
```

Usage:

```
numberOfToCount[{"lollypop", "lollypop", "the beatles"}, toCount, excludeList]
numberOfToCount[{"lollypop", "lollypop", "candy"}, toCount, excludeList]

(*
-> 2
-> Excluded
*)
```

Comment: +1. I suggest to change `And @@ ((! MemberQ[list, #]) & /@ excludeList)` to `! MemberQ[list, Alternatives @@ excludeList]` - this will be more efficient (I considered a similar problem here: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node472.html, where the efficiency issued were also discussed). For a very long list of excluded words, this `Intersection[list, excludeList] === {}` will be better than any of the above, in terms of speed.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the words, try eg

```
dl = DictionaryLookup[];

Select[dl, 
 StringFreeQ[#, ___ ~~ "ies" ~~ ___] && 
 StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ "loll" ~~ ___] &]
 (*
 -> {"loll", "lolled", "lolling", "lollipop", "lollipops", "lollop", "lolloped", "lolloping", "lollops", "lolls", "lolly"}
 *)
```

and you can count them by adding `//Count` at the end (say).

EDIT: It seems I misunderstood your question. If what you're asking is: count the number of times "canapes" appears in a list, which list does not include "modifiable", then:

```
dl2 = {"titivation", "curving", "doppelgangers", "objurgations", 
"canapes", "invaluable", "modifiable", "dissect", "ominousness", 
"sentinel"}

If[Not@MemberQ[dl2, "modifiable"], Count[dl2, "canapes"], False]
(*
-> False
*)
```

while

```
If[Not@MemberQ[dl2, "plate"], Count[dl2, "canapes"], False]
```

excludes "plate", thus giving 1 for this list.

But I am confused by your comments ("This code is returning a preliminary selection of lists that I'm running other searches on, so I need to keep the list intact" which list? they're all kept intact by the code above) so I must still be missing something.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate that into the code I already have, where I'm not returning words, but whole lists that include the words? Inside the `MemberQ` brackets somewhere?

Comment: This code is returning a preliminary selection of lists that I'm running other searches on, so I need to keep the list intact.

Comment: @acl Re your edit. I understood the OP wants to exclude based on a _list_ of terms, not just one ("plate" in your example). Or perhaps my answer is more complicated than it should be

Comment: @belisarius well if that's the case, I guess your answer does the job so no point in mapping mine over lists